# What is a stanza in Linux context and where does the world come from?

Tags: networking, configuration, etc

I searched a lot to find an actual meaning of this word. I found that they are line of text in configuration files but I am not sure if they also mean something else in Linux context and outside.

Answer (score 4):

A stanza is a piece of a configuration file, for example:

```
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

This is a stanza from the Apache `sites-available` configuration file that controls logging, located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` when you have Apache installed.

The origin may be googled, this is what I had [found](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stanza).

Comment: thanks for the info. Is there a limit to how many lines long is a piece to be considered stanza? Is a single line in a configuration file considered a stanza. Is a piece that contains 80% of the file considered stanza ? Is the whole file also a stanza ?

Comment: yoyo, sorry about the delay. Admins/users tend to group the similar objects or functions within a specific config file together to produce a stanza. This makes the parts of the config file easier to read and manipulate, just by having them groups together.